# Tkinter Grid Layout

Tags: python, python-2.7, user-interface, tkinter, grid

So iv'e been experimenting with tkinter's grid, and have run into a brick wall.

So basically i'm trying to create a grid in which I can place multiple elements in like images, buttons, etc. So iv'e been able to understand how to get the buttons placed within frames using row/columns. But when I specify that I want my first button to be in column 0 and row 0 it'll go to top left but if i specifiy column 2 row 0 rather than leaving a gap and placing it in the second column it'll just put the button right next to the first one.

So this is an example of what my problem is and what i'm trying to achieve.

```
I want B1 to be Column = 0, Row = 0
I want B2 to be Column = 2, Row = 0
I want B3 to be Column = 3, Row = 4

What i'm Getting:                     
-------------
|  B1 |  B2 |
|-----  ----|
|  B3 |     |
------------- 

What I want:
------------------------
| B1 |    | B2 |       |
|-----    ------       |
|                      |
|                      |
|                      |
|                 -----|
|                 | B3 |
|                 -----|
------------------------
```

Could someone please tell me how i can achieve this. I am using python 2.7.11.

And another questions apart from that is that I also want to know how i can place an image which is generally larger then a button to fit inside the grid but maintain the positions of the buttons and not break the grid.

Thanks, and sorry in advance if my questions is to simple or hard to understand what i'm trying to ask for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a column is empty, it's width will be zero. If a row is empty it's height will be zero. If you want gaps, you'll need to either explicitly give the row or column a minimum size, or put an in visible element in it.

Comment: I did exactly that just now, added in another row/column and gave it a label which does absolutely nothing besides create "empty" space. This label has a fixed width. Although I think there must be a better way to do it than this because it just doesn't seem right for some reason. But it does work so i'm not one to argue about whats right and wrong. Appreciate you taking your time to answer my question. Will approve answer in a day.

Comment: @SirCodelot: simply put, `grid` has no way of knowing how wide you want a column, or how tall you want a row, unless you tell it. Just because you have an image of width X in column 1, tkinter can't assume that you want every column to be width X. `grid` is a way of arranging widgets, not for arranging empty space. Yet, it gives you that flexibility if you need it.